# "Unbound prefix" error in layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm getting an XML parsing error of "`unbound prefix`" on the `app:` line in an `activity_main.xml` file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:rb_color="#0099CC"
    >
 ...
```

Where `rb_color` is defined in `res/values/attrs.xml`  like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RippleBackground">
        <attr name="rb_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="rb_strokeWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="rb_radius" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="rb_duration" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="rb_rippleAmount" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="rb_scale" format="float"/>
        <attr name="rb_type" format="enum">
            <enum name="fillRipple" value="0"/>
            <enum name="strokeRipple" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I'm following instructions from [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1107).

But as the ripple code there is implemented as a single java file then rather than build the ripple code as a library then incorporate the library into my project, I'm just putting the ripple source java file directly into my project.

Presumably I need to change the app: to something else to reference the `rb_color` to set it, but how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add following line to your parent View:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Like this

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ....
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works if the parent view is the outer most view, as it is in my code posting. However if I try and add another RelativeLayout embedded within the main RelativeLayout and add the app: line to the nested  RelativeLayout then it no longer works, even if I add the xmlns line to the nested layout. Why would that be?

Comment: It doesn't matter where's your app:attribute is, always put xmlns:app in first view (outer most).